# Dashboard show only published pages instead of all pages

Tags: pages, dashboard

Is there a way to view only the published pages instead of all the pages on the wordpress dashboard? I almost never need to use the drafts, and I would like to be able to get to my published pages easier.
Thanks in advance :)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution. Works for me.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'customize_pages_admin_menu_callback' );

function customize_pages_admin_menu_callback() {
    global $submenu;
    foreach ( $submenu['edit.php?post_type=page'] as $key => $value ) {
        if ( in_array( 'edit.php?post_type=page', $value ) ) {
            $submenu['edit.php?post_type=page'][ $key ][2] = 'edit.php?post_status=publish&post_type=page';
        }
    }
}
```

further, you can also hide **All** using CSS if needed.

```
<style>
    .post-type-page .subsubsub .all{ display:none}
</style>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code :) I'm not familiar with wordpress, where am I supposed to paste this, please?

Comment: You can place this code in your themes' functions.php file.

Comment: YES, it worked! Thank you!